# changing folder name, matlab

Tags: file, matlab

I want to set path for my text file programmatically. e.g.,

```
file = 'H:\user4\matlab\myfile.txt';
[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(file)

pathstr =    H:\user4\matlab

name =    myfile

ext =    .txt
```

I want to write all file in `H:\user4\myfile`. How can I get this name.

I want     `newfilepath=strcat(pathstr,'myfile').`

Obviously it gives `H:\user4\matlab\myfile` what I don't want. How can I write my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the parent path manually:

```
islashes = strfind(pathstr,filesep());
newfilepath=fullfile(pathstr(1:islashes(end)),'..','myfile')
```

which uses also [fullfile](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html), [filesep](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html) and [strfind](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html).
`Fullfile` is really nice to concatenate strings while working with files and paths.

Or use `'..'` which Matlab will understand and thus will refer to the parent directory of the preceding directory:

```
newfilepath=fullfile(pathstr,'..','myfile')
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use `fileparts` twice and then `fullfile`:

```
file = 'H:\user4\matlab\myfile.txt';
[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(file);
pathstr = fileparts(pathstr);
fullfile(pathstr, [name ext])
```